# Unifying (tweets/recordtypes) from differents sources in F#

Tags: f#, types

I am getting tweets from three different sources, and each source has more or less data, each source gives me a seq of record types. Let's say:

```
type Tweet1 = { id:int64; text:string;}
type Tweet2 = { id:int64; text:string; user_name:string}
type Tweet3 = { id:int64; text:string; user_name:string; date:DateTime}
```

How does one go about to unify the three sequences, `seq<Tweet1>, seq<Tweet2>, seq<Tweet3>` ?

I was thinking about using:

- an interface but then I wil lose data when upcasting  ( also I cant seem to get a record type to implement an intertface )
- Creating automaticaly a record type with Reflection with all proprietes option type except the ones that are shared, and then map all the record types to this one, but that does not seem very natural

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You could use `Seq.map` to map the Tweet1 and Tweet2 records into the Tweet3 type since that seems to hold the "most" information.

Comment: You could also change `user_name` and `date` to Options, as not all data sources provide those fields.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest option is to define a record that contains all information, but those that may be missing are stored as `option` values (and will be filled with `None` when the information is not available):

```
type Tweet = 
  { id:int64; text:string; 
    user_name:option<string>; date:option<DateTime> }
```

Another way I can think of is to store information about tweets using a data structure like this:

```
type TweetInfo = 
  | Tweet of int64 * string
  | WithUser of string * TweetInfo 
  | WithDate of DateTime * TweetInfo
```

The values from the first record would be turned into `Tweet(id, text)` and the values of the last record would be turned into `WithDate(posted, WithUser(user, Tweet(id, text)))`. A collection of type `list<TweetInfo>` can combine both plain tweets as well as tweets with additional information.

Architecturally, this is a bit similar to the *decorator* design pattern, because you can add additional information to the basic tweet structure. This probably isn't more useful than the basic record, but you can use this trick to add more generality.

You can also add members to extract the properties (using the member syntax). A date and user information would probably return `option<DateTime>` and `option<string>`.